# Logstash's kafka input does not work properly with multiple pipelines

Tags: logstash

I configured the logstash pipeline as shown below. (Configured with k8s )

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: logging
  name: logstash-pipelines
  labels:
    app: logstash
data:
  pipelines.yml: |
    - pipeline.id: dev-a
      pipeline.workers: 1
      path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/dev-a-logstash.conf"
    - pipeline.id: dev-b
      pipeline.workers: 1
      path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/dev-b-logstash.conf"
  dev-a-logstash.conf: |
    input {
      kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "${KAFKA_SERVER}:${KAFKA_PORT}"
        group_id => "dev-a"
        topics => ["dev-a"]
        consumer_threads => 1
        }
    }

    filter {
     json {
       source => "message"
     }
     if [log_processed][logTarget] == "monitor" {
      drop { }
     }
    } 

    output{
    #  stdout {
    #    codec => rubydebug
    #  }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}"]
        index => "dev-a-%{+YYYY.MM}"
        action => "create"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
      }
    }
  dev-b-logstash.conf: |
    input {
      kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "${KAFKA_SERVER}:${KAFKA_PORT}"
        group_id => "dev-b"
        topics => ["dev-b"]
        consumer_threads => 1
        }
    }

    filter {
     json {
       source => "message"
     }
     if [logTarget] == "monitor" {
      drop { }
     }
    } 

    output{
    #  stdout {
    #    codec => rubydebug
    #  }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}"]
        index => "dev-b-%{+YYYY.MM}"
        action => "create"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
      }
    }
```

And the logstash deployment has

```
...
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-pipelines
            items:
              - key: pipelines.yml
                path: pipelines.yml
        - name: pipeline-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-pipelines
            items:
              - key: dev-a-logstash.conf
                path: dev-a-logstash.conf
              - key: dev-b-logstash.conf
                path: dev-b-logstash.conf
...
```

And only dev-a's topic has data, and dev-b has no data stored.
However, in the logs stored in elasticsearch, dev-b also has the contents of dev-a's topic.
[Screen viewed in kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVAZm.png)

Why is this happening? Did I configure something wrong?
For reference, in the past, without installing elasticsearch and kafka on k8, kafka was working fine with the same pipeline on 7.10 for elasticsearch and 3.1.0 for logstash.

Tested versions
logstash, elasticsearch version :7.17.10 ( I also tried 8.8.1 and it was the same )
kafka version : 3.4.1